# I want to transform the following equation into a summation: $G(u,v) = \frac{u}{n}\delta_0(v) + ... + \frac{u}{n}\delta_1(v)$

Tags: calculus, summation

I want to transform the following equation into a summation:

$G(u,v) = \frac{u}{n}\delta_0(v) + ... + \frac{u}{n}\delta_1(v)$, where $\delta_i$ can take any fraction between $0$ and $1$, but $0$ and $1$ need to be included, and we need that $\frac{u}{n}+...+\frac{u}{n}=1$.

For example $n=10$, then $\frac{u}{10}\delta_0(v) +...+ \frac{u}{10}\delta_1(v)=1$

My attempt was: $G(u,v) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{u}{n}\delta_{\frac{i}{n}}(v)$.

However, if $n=2$ we get $\frac{u}{2}\delta_0(v) + \frac{u}{2}\delta_{\frac{1}{2}}(v) + \frac{u}{2}\delta_1(v)$, which meanse that $\frac{u}{n}+...+\frac{u}{n}=1$ isn't satisfied.

Comment: Try $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{u}{n}\delta_{\frac{i}{n-1}}(v)$